# Is it possible to relay access_token from one web api to another in IdentityServer4

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, authorization, identityserver4

Scenario : I have a client, two web apis and IdentityServer4 Token server. Client has both  web apis in his scope and can call them individually. But lets say when client calls one web api and that api needs to call the other by passing access token it received. In coming token is authorized for both services. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I just came across Extension Grants which supports non standard token delegation. Check [official docs](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/release/topics/extension_grants.html#extension-grants)...might be helpful!